# REQUEST: Playful elephants

Tags: sound-effects, recommendations, sound-libraries, request, animals

I am cutting a nature doc about deforestation and I have hit a brick wall on a certain scene.

In this scene, we are in an elephant habitat and there are about 6 adult elephants that are bathing in the river and wrestling on the shore and in the jungle foliage (all CU or MCU). I have cut all of the specific actions, but I am wanting to convey some joy in these elephants. Everything for elephant vocals that I have is either vintage or a huge distressed bellow/scream.

Can anyone recommend a library or a private sale?

Answer (score 2):

Two resources to try:

1. Ann Krober at [Sound Mountain](http://www.soundmountain.com/). She oversees a vast library of sounds that may or may not include playful elephants.
2. The [Macaulay Library](http://macaulaylibrary.org/). From their site:

> The Macaulay Library is the world's largest and oldest scientific
>   archive of biodiversity audio and video recordings. Our mission is to
>   collect and preserve recordings of each species' behavior and natural
>   history, to facilitate the ability of others to collect and preserve
>   such recordings, and to actively promote the use of these recordings
>   for diverse purposes spanning scientific research, education,
>   conservation, and the arts.

Best of luck to ya -

Comment: I had not though of the Macaulay Library.  Thanks @JayJennings.
I got in touch with Ann Kroeber and Chris Watson.  I think Chris might have me covered. Research has shown that, despite their appearance, elephants are pretty quiet creatures.

Answer (score 2):

There's a database of elephant sounds at http://www.elephantvoices.org/  and you could try The Elephant Listening Project: http://www.birds.cornell.edu/BRP/elephant/